# Consulta de ranking en base a una fecha y un id Bigquery (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lo que quiero hacer en una consulta es, teniendo en una columna el id, fecha_actualizacion

Generar una nueva columna (orden) que me indique cual fue el primero que se actualizó, cual fue el segundo, etc para ese id. Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Normalmente las preguntas de quiero hacer esto, sin exponer lo que has preguntado, terminan como cerradas. Puedes darle a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Puedes buscar en la web, sobre [row_number bigquery](https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-row-number-function/#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20BigQuery%20ROW_NUMBER,incrementing%20number%20to%20the%20order.) y verás que es simple.

Comment: Das muy pocos detalles, pq hay tres que tienen 1 en el campo orden?

Comment: Porque la jerarquía solo se aplica a determinado id, es decir, para el id=1 tenes el primero, segundo, tercero, cuarto, quinto y sexto. Para el id=2 tenes el primero, segundo y tercero. Y para el id=3 tenes solo primero y segundo

Answer (score 0):

buscando la solución me encontré con la siguiente para el ejemplo que coloqué en la pregunta, es:

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fecha_actualizacion) as orden
FROM table
```

Allí creará una tabla con el orden propuesto.
Saludos,